# Polynomial inequalities vs rational inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, rational-functions

A question from one of the comprehension questions I have is:

How would the intervals of the solution set differ between a polynomial inequality and a rational inequality?

I have tried to research the topic but have come up short. I know that rational functions can have vertical asymptotes and restrictions on the domain but I am not sure if this is relevant or what the difference specifically would be. I was thinking it might be because the rational function would have a hole in the intervals and a polynomial would not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two differences:

A polynomial inequality
(PI)
can always be replaced
by a PI with one side zero.
That is,
$p(x) > q(x)$
is the same as
$p(x)-q(x) 
> 0
$.
A rational inequality
(RI)
can not, because
you do not know the sign of
the denominator;
$\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}
> \frac{c(x)}{d(x)}
$
can not safely be replaced by
$\frac{a(x)d(x)-b(x)c(x)}{b(x)d(x)}
> 0
$
because $b(x)$ and/or 
$d(x)$ might change signs 
unexpectedly.

Of course,
as you said,
denominators can be zero,
which can be annoying.